# Regex : Match word not preceded or followed by a dot

Tags: regex

I try to write a simple regex that match alphanumeric word not followed or preceded by a dot, I tried to adapat answers from other questions but it don't work.

```
String = table.field1 + field2
```

I want to capture only the word "field2", but currently I match too much.

Here is my regex:

```
(table\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)|(?<!\.)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/BYg35X/1

Comment: Maybe just `\b(?<!\.)\w+\b(?!\.)`? Why did you use `(table\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)|(?<!\.)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+`, what are the pattern requirements?

Comment: what regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\b(?<!\.)\w+\b(?!\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sAUHJZ/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\.)` - there must be no `.` immediately on the left of the current location
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\b(?!\.)` - a word boundary immediately after which there should be no `.` char.

Comment: I came up with the same answer, only i would have writen the negative lookahead for the "." before the boundary. Is there any reason for this order in terms of performance?

Comment: @DuesserBaest Some regex engines find word boundary positions as part of the regex execution optimization, so I prefer this way.